# Type does not conform to protocol - typealias to another protocol

Tags: ios, swift2, protocols

I'm facing an anoying problem and I was hopping that you guys could help me with that.

I have two protocols and one class:

```
protocol Prot1: AnyObject {

}

protocol Prot2 {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
}

class TheClass: Prot2 {
    typealias T = Prot1
}
```

This causes the compiler to say:

- Type 'TheClass' does not conform to protocol 'Prot2'.

In the navigation it shows more details:

- Protocol requires nested type 'T'
- Possibly intended match 'T' (aka 'Prot1') does not conform to 'AnyObject'

I realy need the associated type to be of the **AnyObject** type. This is why I need help.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thank you very much.

**OBS: I'm using swift 2.3**

Comment: A protocol does not conform to itself. The way to resolve `typealias T` in TheClass is with a type that _adopts_ Prot1 — not with Prot1 itself.

Comment: The protocol doesn't conforms to itself in the exemple. I have a protocol that references another protocol. The problem is that I need the associated type to be an object, so I can use the real object in an objc collection.

Comment: did you get the solution? @Awe

Comment: Nope. I didn't :/

Comment: You need to think more about what I said. The next to last line needs to specify an object type, not a protocol name.

Comment: I see. So I can't use a protocol. Must be a type. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To show the nature of what you can do here, I will simplify the example slightly. This is legal:

```
protocol Prot {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
}
class TheClass: Prot {
    typealias T = AnyObject // fine
}
```

This is also legal:

```
protocol Prot {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
}

class TheClass: Prot {
    typealias T = NSObject // fine
}
```

That's because NSObject is a type that is an *adopter* of AnyObject.

But this (what you're trying to do) is *not* legal:

```
protocol Prot {
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
}

protocol SecondProt : AnyObject {

}

class TheClass: Prot {
    typealias T = SecondProt // error
}
```

The reason is that SecondProt is another *protocol* that adopts AnyObject. That is not something that can go in the `typealias T` slot.

This has nothing to do with the special nature of AnyObject. We can get the same error without mentioning AnyObject anywhere:

```
protocol P {}

protocol Prot {
    associatedtype T: P
}

protocol SecondProt : P {

}

class TheClass: Prot {
    typealias T = SecondProt // error
}
```

Again, if we supply a *type* that adopts P, we're fine:

```
protocol P {}

protocol Prot {
    associatedtype T: P
}

struct S : P {

}

class TheClass: Prot {
    typealias T = S // fine
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matt. I will mark your question as the solution because you has shown that it not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change Anyobject to Any is ok, or delete Anyobject. Anyobject is class type.[Type Casting for Any and AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342)

Comment: I can't use 'Any' because I am using an Objc collection that only accepts AnyObjects.

Comment: If you delete 'Anyobject' in Prot2, can objc collection accepts?

Comment: No, it can't. This error message is shown: "Cannot convert value of type 'Self.T' to expected argument type 'AnyObject?'"

Answer (score -1):

This snippet compiles. But I am not sure if it's what you're looking for...

```
protocol Prot1: AnyObject 
{

}

protocol Prot2 
{
    associatedtype T: AnyObject
}

class TheClass: Prot2 
{
    typealias U = Prot1
    typealias T = AnyObject
}
```

Comment: Here it doesn't. It says "Type 'TheClass' does not conform to protocol 'Prot2'.". Maybe it's because I using swift 2.3?

Comment: Hey @Adolfo. Were you able to compile this using swift 3?

Comment: Hi @Awe I tested it on IBM bluemix Swift compiler. And went well 